# Error when syncing with Github for Mac app

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I'm getting this error after I try to login when syncing. I have no idea what is causing it and can't seem to find any info about it when searching. I know I'm putting in the correct user and password. Anyone have any ideas?

`2012-11-12 09:49:20.122 GitHub for Mac Login[64648:707] Error reading generic password: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.
2012-11-12 09:49:20.123 GitHub for Mac Login[64648:707] Error reading internet password: The specified attribute does not exist.
error: unable to read askpass response from '/Applications/GitHub.app/Contents/MacOS/GitHub for Mac Login'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
 (256)`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support question for a software product. And is also most likely out of date.

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out. Had to change the primary remote repository address in the github app settings. Changed it to the SSH address and now it works. *shrug*

Comment: This just happened to me as well.  Worked fine last night, strangely.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The exact same thing happened to me too. The question is why though?

Comment: Happened here too.. Shocking!